Using cryptsetup and mount without sudo
I'm trying to build a CLI to easily manage the backups I have on my hard drives. Currently I use LUKS to encrypt the drives and duplicity to manage the backup process, and I have a simple bash script to semi-automate the process, which I run with sudo.
The process of the CLI that I'd like to program would roughly be:

Decrypt drive with cryptsetup open UUID=<uuid_of_drive> name
Mount the decripted drive's fs mount /dev/mapper/name /media/name
Do backup stuff with duplicity duplicity /dir/to/backup file://media/name/backups/

My question is: is there any way to do this without needing root permissions? The first two commands require it, and I'd like to know if there's a way to do it. I know for example that programs such as the Nautilus file manager can decrypt and mount drives and I'm pretty sure it runs without sudo permissions.

Nautilus uses udisks for these operations which doesn't require authentication in certain situation (like mounting or unlocking removable devices). From a script you can use udisksctl:
udisksctl unlock --block-device /dev/sdxY
udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/mapper/luks-<UUID>

